# regex to extract part of filename

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract part of a filename that is contained in a xml string

Sample

```
<assets>
<media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf7.JPG"  valign="top"/>
<media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf5.JPG"  valign="top"/>
<media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf4.JPG"  valign="top"/>
</assets>
```

I want to match and retrieve the **560PEgnR** portion from all entries, regardless of the filename

So far I have

```
/assets/(.*)/*"
```

But it doesn't do what I want

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try with:

```
/assets/(.*?)/.*
```

`.*` is gready, but using `?` it stops on the first `/`.

Comment: The last part still needs a bit fixing fixing: ``/assets/(.*?)/.*``. But you can throw it all away and just use ``/assets/(.*?)/``.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this returns the filename as well (ie 560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf5.JPG). I only need the 560PEgnR

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively...

```
/assets/([^/])+/
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several alternatives. Your mistake is that your .* part also includes the '/', so either you make it less greedy (as hsz proposed above) or you exclude a '/' from the matching group like this `/assets/([^/]*).*`.

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex approach

```
>>> string="""
... <assets>  
... <media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf7.JPG"  valign="top"/>
... <media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf5.JPG"  valign="top"/>
... <media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf4.JPG"  valign="top"/>
... </assets>                                                                                  
... """           

>>> for line in string.split("\n"):
...     if "/assets/" in line:
...         print line.split("/assets/")[-1].split("/")[0]
...
560PEgnR
560PEgnR
560PEgnR
```

Answer (score 1):

Properly parsing the XML and avoiding the unnecessary use of regex:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<assets>
<media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf7.JPG"  valign="top"/>
<media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf5.JPG"  valign="top"/>
<media width="100%" height="100%" img="/assets/560PEgnR/kVvNKfOX7w9tf4.JPG"  valign="top"/>
</assets>
"""

xmltree = etree.fromstring(xml)

for media in xmltree.iterfind(".//media"):
    path = media.get('img')
    print path.split('/')[-2]
```

Gives:

```
560PEgnR
560PEgnR
560PEgnR
```